# Получить событие неудачной разблокировки

Tags: java, android

В приложении нужно отлавливать события неудачной разблокировки экрана. Как можно это реализовать? Как я поняла, нужно использовать сервисы, но опыта в этом не было, поэтому хотелось бы узнать как это можно сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения событий об удачной/неудачной попытке разблокировки телефона необходимо создать ресивер, наследуемый от [`DeviceAdminReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html) и переопределить метод `onPasswordFailed(...)`:

```
@Override
public void onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent, UserHandle user) {
    super.onPasswordFailed(context, intent, user);
}
```

Также, можно получить количество неудачных попыток ввода:

```
DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
int failedPasswordAttempts = devicePolicyManager.getCurrentFailedPasswordAttempts();
```

Разумеется, перед этим необходимо дать приложению администраторские права.

Подробнее:  [`Device Administration API`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

Comment: т. е. если приложение не запущенно, все равно будет работать?

Comment: @Arina, В случае объявление ресивера в манифесте -- да.